# Is Blogger API Paid?

Tags: android, google-blogger-api

I'm new to coding in android and I have an idea of developing an app for a blog. There are RSS Feeds and API as far as I know.

I use Google APIs, exactly Blogger API. But some Google APIs are paid. My questions are:

1. Is Blogger API paid?
2. How do I figure out if the API service is paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know blogger API is free.

You can check all the details in the Google APIs console:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/939657648296/apiui/api

You can find how many requests per day are free.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Api is paid for accessing domain information i.e access to public information of other users. It's free if you just try to access your Blog's information up to certain number of requests per day.